# reg exp - search()

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript)

how to write a variable into a reg exp pattern?

here the pattern always is /value/i

```
var value = inp.val();
if(search_list[key].search(/value/i) >= 0) alert('ok');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the implicit literal syntax you could change to be explicit.

```
new RegExp(value, "i")
```